# JEST can't use string template in test.each

Tags: jestjs

Im trying to print the test values to string template...

```
    test.each([{ related: 'names', value: 'The name', merging: true }])(
        'When using $related with $value then....',
        async ({ related, value, merging }: { related: string; value: string; merging: boolean }) => {
            //Arrange
            
            //Act
           
            //Assert
           
            expect(....)
        },
    );
```

I expect the out put to be: `When using names with The name then....`
But its actually: `When using $related with $value then....`

Whats am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a table instead.

```
test.each`
related | value | merging
${'names'} | ${'value'} | ${true}
${'other name'} | ${'other value'} | ${true}
`(
  "then using $related with $value then....",
 async ({ related, value, merging } ) => {
    //Arrange

    //Act

    //Assert

    expect(related).toBe(merging);
  }
);
```

Comment: I can't, I need to pass pure array. thanks

Comment: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2021/12/parameterized-tests-in-javascript-with-jest.html Shows how to pass a pure array.